# My .viminfo file doesn't have a writing permissions, how should i grant it?

Tags: vim

How do you change the permissions, so you can write to a file?

Answer (score 3):

Via the commands below in a terminal

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.viminfo
chmod gu+rw ~/.viminfo
```

---

- The 1st command corrects the owner and the group for your user
- The 2nd command adds (`+`) `r`ead and `w`rite permissions to your `g`roup and `u`ser